$\mathbb{P}(4W_1^2 > W_4^2)$, where $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion
I would like to find $\mathbb{P}(4W_1^2 > W_4^2)$, where $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion, but I am not entirely sure how to proceed.
Originally I thought the trick would be to rearrange and factorise into $\mathbb{P}((2W_1-W_4)(2W_1+W_4) > 0)$ and use some kind of reflection principal argument on the first factor, but maybe there is a better way?

$W_4=(W_4-W_1)+W_1$ and independent sum. Rest should be plain Calculus.
